# SQL -- IF EXISTS doesnt work

Tags: php, mysql, sql, if-statement, exists

Im trying to doing a sql query that is not working, I would like to add one element to a table only and only if that value is not in the table, something like that:

```
IF EXISTS (Select `id` from `artists` Where `artist`='"$artist"') Do Nothing
ELSE      Insert into `artists` (`artist`) values('".$artist."')
```

What is the best way to do that?

PS: I have tried to look for that information by google and in the forum, but I dont understand the idea

Thank you very much in advance

PS2: Sorry, Its a MYSQL database

Comment: Maybe a duplicated entry: [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361340/how-to-insert-if-not-exists-in-mysql)

Answer (score 2):

What about using IF NOT EXISTS...

Something like:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (Select `id` from `artists` Where `artist`='"$artist"') Insert into `artists` (`artist`) values('".$artist."')
```